# .Net Core Tests Fails in CDPX Build Pipeline

Tags: .net-core, msbuild, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I have a .net core 3.0 azure function project in an existing solution. While it builds and runs fine in visual studio,  the CDPX for it sometimes failed with message-

```
MSB4025: The project file could not be loaded. Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1
```

The YAML being used-

```
steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet core test'
  inputs:
    command: test
    projects: '**\*ProjectDllName.dll'
```

Running the same build again fixes the issue. But this is happening very frequently now.

Comment: Test with the Yaml. But I couldn't reproduce this issue.  Which agent are you using(self-hosted or Microsoft-hosted)? Check if this [Blog](http://chamindac.blogspot.com/2019/09/resolving-azure-devops-build-error-data.html) could give you some help. You could try to specify `.csproj` file instead of `.dll` file.

Comment: its is a microsoft hosted agent. Let me try with csproj instead of dll